# HTML5 boilerplate issue with tables

Tags: html, jsp, html-table, boilerplate

I tried adding Irish's html5boilerplate to a page but now am seeing all this extra space between my table tr's. There's no CSS that controls the page. It's just jsp code and html. Basically, there's code being added where the pages need to be in standards mode. All other pages had small, manageable differences. But this is an older page laid out using tables. I attempted

```
 <pre>
     <style>
      table{display:block}
      tr{margin:0;padding:0}
    </style>
   </pre>
```

to remove the margins to no avail.

When i add this to the head, I see strange effects in chrome and ff:

```
  <pre>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    </pre>
```

If there's no easy fix, I guess adding the head will have to wait till the page gets redone.

Comment: Have you tried this? table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}

Comment: Giving it a try now. Thanks

Comment: No dice. I'm still seeing the spaces between rows. If you can think of any other quick fix suggestions, please let me know. Thanks for trying

Comment: Just to be clear, you aren't adding the <pre> tags in your markup right?